# Nested <Text> tag not appearing in React Native App

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to conditionally render some text on a React Native app using Javascript but it is not appearing for some reason.

Here is my code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import firebase from '../firebase/firestore';


class FormBuilder extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.firestoreRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Forms');
        this.state = {
          isLoading: true,
          formArr: []
        };
      }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.unsubscribe = this.firestoreRef.onSnapshot(this.getCollection);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.unsubscribe();
    }



    getCollection = (querySnapshot) => {
        const formArr = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
          const { FormId, Company, CreatedBy, CreatedWhen, LastModified, LastModifiedBy, Payload } = res.data().formMetaData;
          formArr.push({
            FormId: FormId,
            Company: Company,
            CreatedBy: CreatedBy,
            CreatedWhen: CreatedWhen,
            LastModified: LastModified,
            LastModifiedBy: LastModifiedBy, 
            Payload: Payload
          });
        });
        this.setState({
            formArr,
          isLoading: false,
       });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading){
          return(
            <View style={styles.preloader}>
              <Text>Loading...</Text>
            </View>
          )
        }
        return(
            <View style={styles.dumb}>
                <Text>Form Data Below</Text>
                <View>
                    <Text>{
                        this.state.formArr.length > 0 ? this.state.formArr.map((item) => {
                            
                            <Text>Hello</Text>
                            

                        }) : <Text>No Forms in Database</Text>
                    
                    }</Text>
                </View>

            </View>
        )
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingBottom: 0
    },
    preloader: {
        paddingTop: 10,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    dumb: {
        borderWidth: 1,
    }

  })
  
  export default FormBuilder;
```

So I am receiving data from a database and I am displaying that data once it has been loaded. The part that I am having trouble with is this line:

```
{this.state.formArr.length > 0 ? this.state.formArr.map((item) => {
   <Text>Hello</Text>

 }) : <Text>No Forms in Database</Text>
}
```

Even if the `this.state.formArr.length > 0` condition is reached, the `<Text>Hello</Text>` will not appear on the screen.

I checked that the condition is being reached because if I replace `<Text>Hello</Text>` with `alert(1)`, the alert will appear.

The only thing that is on the screen is the `<Text>Form Data Below</Text>`

Am I missing something obvious? I know that the condition is executing, so why wont the `<Text>` tag render? Let me know if you guys have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem i see in your code is that after mapping an array you are not returning a  component thats why its not showing anything on the screen.

**Try this**

```
{
  this.state.formArr.length > 0 ? (
    this.state.formArr.map(item => {
      return <Text>Hello</Text>;
    })
  ) : (
    <Text>No Forms in Database</Text>
  );
}
```